# Magento 2 order information: How to add links dynamically?

Tags: customer-account, order-status, tabs, link, magento2.3

When a customer selects an order in his order history he is redirected to the order information page.

If the items have not yet been shipped there is only one tab available: Items ordered. If its shipped and invoiced two other tabs are available: Shipment and Invoice.

**Where can I find the code responsible for showing and not showing the aforementioned tabs?** I am asking because I want to create a custom tab and dynamically decide whether it should be shown or not.

Comment: you can check this file
vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\layout\sales_order_info_links.xml

Comment: I used this file, more precicely a copy of it in my module, to statically add a custom link. My questions is however how can I influence at runtime whether the link really should be displayed or not, i.e. add a custom link only if the items has already been shipped.